# TortoiseSVN overlay icons disappeared in FreeCommander

Tags: svn, icons, tortoisesvn

TortoiseSVN overlay icons disappeared in FreeCommander after installing latest 1.9.2.26806-x64 version. Works fine in explorer however. Worked fine FreeCommander with 1.8.10. Removing/reinstalling/restarting/repairing/downgrade (now fails to show even with 1.8.10 version) does not help. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem, too. Solved it by 1) uninstalling TortoiseSVN completely (then reboot) 2) uninstall TortoiseOverlays which I had installed separately to try if this helps; then rebooting again; 3) making sure everything related to TortoiseSVN and TortoiseOverlays was cleaned up in the registry as well. Another reboot, clean install of 1.8.10 and once again a reboot and everything worked again.

Comment: Thanks, works for 1.8.10, fails for 1.9.2. Possible bug for developers.